# LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL can't assign icon to Finder sidebar item in 10.7 and older

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to add a link to a folder in the Finder sidebar. It works fine in every other OS, but when I try to add the icon to this item in Mac OS X 10.7 or Mac OS X 10.8 nothing happens. In 10.6, however, my code works great.

```
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.syncFolderPath]; 
IconRef iconRef;
FSRef fref;

CFURLRef iconURLRef = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/pathTo/icon.icns"];
CFURLGetFSRef(iconURLRef, &fref);
RegisterIconRefFromFSRef('SSBL', 'ssic', &fref, &iconRef);

// Create a reference to the shared file list.
LSSharedFileListRef favoriteItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL);

if (favoriteItems) {
    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(favoriteItems, kLSSharedFileListItemBeforeFirst, NULL, iconRef, url, NULL, NULL);

    if (item){
        CFRelease(item);
    }
}   

CFRelease(favoriteItems);
```

Can somebody give me advice? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you checked that `RegisterIconRefFromFSRef` returns `noErr`?

Comment: hey guys have you found any solution